# How would I prove ${n^{2n} \gt (2n)!}$ using mathematical induction?

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

This is what I have done. I checked for $n=1,2$ and $3$ in the first step. I did the assumption for $n=k$ and the claim of $n=k+1$ in the second step, but I don't understand how the step no. $3$ works so if anyone can do this a description of what you are doing in each step would be really helpful.

Comment: It's wrong for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: For each integer $n>3$, the inequality is true by AM-GM.  We have $$\frac{n^2}{2}> (2n-1)\cdot 1$$ and $$n^2>(2n-j)j$$ for $j=2,3,\ldots,n-1$.  So, $$n^{2n}=(2n)\,\left(\frac{n^2}{2}\right)\,n\,\left(n^2\right)^{n-2}>(2n)\,\big((2n-1)\cdot 1)\,n\,\prod_{j=2}^{n-1}\,j(2n-j)=(2n)!\,.$$  It remains to check the cases $n=1,2,3$, but as Michael Rozenberg said, this is false for $n=1$, but also $n=2$.

Comment: @Batominovski It is a quite elegant way you provided there but the OP refers explicitly to the usage of the concept of mathematical induction.

Comment: @mrtaurho  That is why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Batominovski Hm, okay. This is indeed a valid argumentation ^^ Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right. But you have to note that the inequality does not hold for $n=1$ and $n=2$ respectively. Therefore your base case is given by $n=3$. You proceeded right by considering the cases $n=k$ and $n=k+1$

> $$\begin{align}
> k^{2k}&>(2k)!\\
> (k+1)^{2(k+1)}&>(2(k+1))!
> \end{align}$$

Now the key behind proving inequlities via induction is to somehow multiply one side of the assumption with a proper factor in order to get the claim. Form hereon you can proceed by showing that the factor which does gets the other side form assumption to claim is either smaller or bigger than the other one respectively.

So lets start with the RHS of our assumption. By using the basic property of the factorial we can conclude that we need to multiply the RHS by the factor $(2k+2)(2k+1)$ to make this side equal to $(2(k+1))!$. So lets apply this multiplication to both sides within our assumption to get

$$\begin{align}
(2k)!(2k+2)(2k+1)&<k^{2k}(2k+2)(2k+1)\\
&<k^{2k}4(k+1)^2\\
&=(2k^k)^2(k+1)^2\\
&\stackrel{?}{<}
\end{align}$$

The next step is a little bit tricky. To show that the RHS is actually smaller than our claimed term for the RHS, $(k+1)^{2(k+1)}$, we need to show that $2k^k<(k+1)^k$. This can be easily done by considering [Bernoullis inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) for $n=k$ and $x=1/k$ respectively. Thus we get

$$1+nx< (1+x)^n\Rightarrow 1+1<\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\Leftrightarrow 2k^k<(k+1)^k$$

Plugging the last result within our calculation so far we get

$$\begin{align}
(2k)!(2k+2)(2k+1)&<k^{2k}(2k+2)(2k+1)\\
&<k^{2k}4(k+1)^2\\
&=(2k^k)^2(k+1)^2\\
&<((k+1)^k)^2(k+1)^2\\
&=(k+1)^{2(k+1)}\\
\Leftrightarrow (2(k+1))!&<(k+1)^{2(k+1)}
\end{align}$$

and now we are done!

Comment: Thanks everyone. Mrtaurho, your answer was the most understandable for me, but i didnt get it all. I will try to figure out everything you did and if I dont understand something I will ask

Comment: I dont understand the part where you multiplied by $(2k+2)(2k+1)$, why did you do it? and how did you get $ 4(k+1)^2$ or how did you get $(2k^k)^2$ from $k^{2k}$

Comment: I just multplied both side by the factor $(2k+2)(2k+1)$. I can do this without any problems. Furthermore form hereon the LHS automatically becomes our claim since $(2k!)(2k+2)(2k+1)=(2k+2)!=(2(k+1))!$ and so we are done with reshaping the LHS. Now we have to get the RHS in the right form. Therefore I argued that the factor $(2k+2)(2k+1)$ is smaller than the factor $(2k+2)(2k+2)$, which should be clear. Now $(2k+2)(2k+2)=2(k+1)2(k+1)=4(k+1)^2$ so I got this factor. For the first term I just applied the relation $4k^{2k}=2^2(k^k)^2=(2k^k)^2$ which are some basic properties of powers.

Comment: okay I think i get everything but the part where we use Bernoullis' inequality. What do we consider and how do we get these numbers?

Comment: As you can see within the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) Bernoulli's inequality can be stated as $$ (1+x)^n>1+nx$$ for some $n\ge 2$ and $x\ge-1,x\ne 0$. Now in order to use this inequality here we can set $n=k$ and $x=1/k$. Since we introduced $k$ earlier with as subsitution for $n$ and furthermore $n$ has to be at least $3$ the conditions for the usage of Bernoulli's inequality are fulfilled. Therefore by plugging the values in we get $$1+k\frac1k<\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\Leftrightarrow 2k^k<(k+1)^k$$ I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: Yes another question. How did you get $4(k+1)^2$ from $(2k+2)(2k+1) when (2k+2)(2k+2) = 4(k+1)^2$

Comment: To be precise I did not stated that $(2k+2)(2k+1)$ equals $4(k+1)^2$. In fact the statement is $(2k+2)(2k+1)\color{red}{<}(2k+2)(2k+2)=4(k+1)^2$ which is totally legitimate.

Comment: Did you take $2k^k<(k+1)^2$ in bernoulis from $(2k^k)^{2}(k+1)^2$ and how did you factor $(2k^k)^2 to (k(k+1)^k)^2$

Comment: oh i see. I thought you were working out the whole RHS and factoring everything as opposed to LHS

Comment: Is everything clear now or do want me to explain something further? In case you are satisfied you could mark my answer as accepted to show that you are not in need of more input :)

Comment: Yes the one i asked after you explained $4(k+1)^2$ please

Comment: Yes, actually I applied Bernoulli's inequality which gave us $2k^k<(k+1)^k$ - not $2k^k<(k+1)^2$ - squared both sides and multiplied by $(k+1)^2$ which leads us to $2k^{2k}(k+1)^2<(k+1)^{2k}(k+1)^2$. Again you have to watch out since there is no equal sign between these two lines.

Comment: thank you very much,everything is clear now.

Comment: Well, in this case I am happy that I could help you. Now you can mark my answer as accepted I would suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ and for $n=2$ it's wrong.

For $n\geq3$ by the assumption of the induction we obtain:
$$(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!<(2n+2)(2n+1)n^{2n}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(2n+2)(2n+1)n^{2n}<(n+1)^{2n+2}$$ or
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n>\sqrt{\frac{4n+2}{n+1}}.$$
Can you end it now?

Now, since $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ increases on $[3,+\infty)$, we obtain:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\geq\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{64}{27}$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{64}{27}>\sqrt{\frac{4n+2}{n+1}},$$ which is true because
$$\frac{64}{27}>2=\sqrt{\frac{4n+4}{n+1}}>\sqrt{\frac{4n+2}{n+1}}.$$

Comment: not really, I cant

Comment: @Amir Handanovic I added something. See now.